# Closed convex hull of a set is the unit ball.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-hulls, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a (real) Banach space and $A \subseteq X^{*}$ some weak*-compact subset of a unit ball in $X^*$. Furthermore, assume that for any functional $f \in A$, we have $-f \in A$. Now we know that, as a corollary of Hahn-Banach, for any $x \in X$ we have
$$\| x\| = \sup \{|f(x)|\ |\ f \in X^*,\ \| f\| \leq 1\}.$$
Is it true that if
$$\| x\| = \sup \{|f(x)|\ |\ f \in A\},\quad \forall x \in X,$$
then the closed convex hull of $A$ is the unit ball of $X^*$? If yes, why? If not, under which conditions would this hold?

Comment: This reads like it was just pulled out of a textbook, no effort shown on your part. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Not out of a textbook. It's a step in the proof of a lemma in a paper I'm currently reading. I asked here because I didn't know whether this was a well-known general argument.

Comment: Please put that in your question then. Keep in mind that the questions are not just for you but for the site i.e., for whom else may look at it using MSE as a reference. Thanks!

Comment: If $A$ is such a subset with the desired property, then the weak* closed convex hull of $A$ is equal to the unit ball of $X^{*}$. This can be shown by a separation argument. If $X$ is reflexive, then the weak* closed convex hull of $A$ coincides with the closed convex hull of $A$, so the result is true in the reflexive case.